Why can't I delete a file named '.' on external NAS with macOS?
I have a Western Digital My Cloud EX2 Ultra and somehow ended up with a . file inside an empty directory.

I tried:

Deleting it with Finder:


Delete it from Terminal:
rm -rf ./*
zsh: sure you want to delete all the files in /Volumes/drive/_delete/. [yn]? y
zsh: no matches found: ./*

rm -rf _delete
rm: _delete: Permission denied

find . -inum 48633179 -delete



Nothing worked. What else can I try?

I run into this occasionally with Mac-originated files on my Synology NAS. Windows sees them, will open them etc but will not delete them. So I log into the NAS itself and use its file manager to delete them. Works a charm.

@SteveRindsberg I have a EX2 Ultra. Following your suggestion, I used the Web Explorer to the delete the folder and it succeeded! Thanks for the suggestion!

I run into this problem occasionally in Windows but trying to remove Mac-originated files on my Synology NAS.
Windows sees them, will open them, etc. but will not copy or delete them.
Instead, I log into the NAS itself and use its file manager to delete the problem files.
So far, works every time.
